# Android app should not scroll back to top of page when rotation occurs while writing a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, android-app

I have downloaded the Stack Exchange app on my phone. Now, if I start typing up a comment, and turn the screen mid-way through my comment:

[image: Illustration of phone rotation from portrait to landscape]

Then, the comment disappears (which is very frustrating after having typed 300 characters...) and, I am scrolled all the way to the top again, where I have to scroll back down to where I was.

Can we fix the app so that tilting the screen doesn't affect how far you are in the page (scroll-wise) or how far you are in your comment (character-wise)?

Also, this is one of my first posts on meta, so how will I know if someone has received my feature-request? Thanks

Comment: @JoshCaswell Android

Comment: Thanks, tagged appropriately.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Great. Is this problem there in apple?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be (wrote this comment in the iOS app to test).

Comment: I kind of liked the original revision of the post body.

Comment: @TinyGiant It used to have the image scrolling, "This is so much fun" :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/VFJuY.gif

Comment: I find this particularly annoying when scrolling through the hot questions list.  If I accidentally turn my phone (say, while briefly setting it on a table) I'm bumped back to the top of the list.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Exactly!

Comment: Scrolling is broken in the app anyway. If I'm reading a question with many long answer, the view jumps half an answer up or down now and then. Is there a bug report for that already?

Comment: I believe once your bug/feature-request is looked at and resolved, someone from the dev teams or mods will tag your post with one of the `status-*` tags (e.g status completed)

Comment: I had that issue in an Android app I wrote. If I remember correctly, Android kills and recreates the activity when screen orientation changes. The app needs to actively save its state (partially filled forms, scroll position) so that Android takes that state into account when recreating

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, and I'm assuming that when they wrote this app, they just set up a different layout for different orientation. The constant saving (like google docs does) may slow the app down, and possibly take up more memory, but it will be greatly beneficial to all of us mobile users!

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, the entire state is supposed to be saved/restored on a screen rotation, it seems I forgot about comments though. I'm looking into this now.

Comment: I bet the StackExchange app is open-source.. Can someone kindly provide a link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.78. I'm not going to send out an update because this is the only fix in the queue for that version right now, but if you'd like it sooner feel free to join our beta channel: [Open beta testing of the Stack Exchange Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app)

Comment: For what it's worth, your comment was actually being persisted, the only thing that was being persisted was the visibility of the commenting UI. On version 1.0.77 (the current prod build) if you rotate a screen mid writing a comment and tap "Add Comment" on the same post again, your pending comment shows up again.

Comment: Great! So are you part of the app development team at Stack Exchange?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia yep, I run the team :)

Comment: I bet the StackExchange app is open-source.. Can someone kindly provide a link to it?